# Escape percent sign (%) in hexdump format

Tags: text-processing, hexdump

#### Problem

I'm trying to emit a hex string like:

```sh
echo hello | hexdump -ve '/1 "_%02X"' ; echo
```

but with `%` instead.

#### Actual vs Expected

```sh
echo hello | hexdump -ve '/1 "%%%02X"' ; echo
```

fails with

```sh
hexdump: bad conversion character %%
```

#### Question

Is there any way to escape `%` in hexdump format string?

Comment: `badconv` is the function causing this in [hexdump-parse.c](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/text-utils/hexdump-parse.c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way to get `hexdump` to emit a '%' character directly.  Perhaps you could continue to emit the '_' character and then pipe the result through `sed` to convert the '_' into a '%'.  Something like this:

```
echo hello | hexdump -ve '/1 "_%02X"' | sed -e 's/_/%/g'
```

which produces:

```
%68%65%6C%6C%6F%0A
```